# chnage the colour of tabs in android

Tags: android, colors, tabs

I am new to android and I created some tabs. However as bock background and text are set to black as default I cant see any text on the tabs.

How can I change the tab background or the text colour please? thanks

Answer (score 1):

To change the `background` of your `TabWidget` just add in your `xml` file:

```
android:background="#b2b2b2"
```

Otherwise if you want to change the color of text you need to create a `Custom Tab` in which you can change the textcolor, font, etc. 
Hope I helped you